How to create a click handler and window.addEventListener in TypeScript (Next.js)?
I have a click handler that I want to listen to any clicks on the window outside of my component:
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutSideClick = (event) => {
      if (!ref.current?.contains(event.target)) {
        setNavActive(false)
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleOutSideClick, false);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleOutSideClick, false);
    };
  }, [ref]);

However, I am getting the error:
Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type. (line 2)
and
Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'never'. (line 3)
How do I specify type in order to get this click handler working?

"I have a click handler that I want to listen to any clicks on the window outside of my component" tread very carefully here, trying to mix imperative DOM handling with React components is not for the faint of heart. You will definitely need to add a type to the event argument to the handler. Also what type did you give to useRef?

You need to set type in the ref.
For example, if you div is a div element:
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)


Assuming your state is:
const [navActive, setNavActive] = useState(false);


Create a ref in the component that has the element as below:
const ref = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();


Add ref attribute to the appropriate element.
<div ref={ref}>...</div>


Handle the outside click event:
 const handleOutSideClick = (
 e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>
) => {
 if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target as HTMLDivElement)) setNavActive(false);
}; 


In your useEffect, handle the keydown event:
useEffect(() => {
 if (navActive) {
   document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
     if (e.key === 'Escape') {
       setNavActive(false);
     }
   });
 } else {
   document.removeEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
     if (e.key === 'Escape') {
       setNavActive(false);
     }
   });
 }
}, [navActive]);



Please endeavour to provide more details of your code next time.
